# How to Interact with web service from ATL Code

Tags: web-services, atl

I want to call simple web service from ATL Code. I am new to both ATL and Webservice. I worked on MFC and VC++. I want to know what should be application type when create ATL project from wizard and how to call web service(already created)

What I tried :-
1. I tried to create sample project for ATL which asks me to select DLL/EXE, I selected EXE considering I will be able to execute however it fails to build. 
2. Searched on internet how to call web service from ATL however I didn't found useful stuff.I am getting confused with ATL and ATL Server terms.

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you wish to use a webservice with ATL and Visual C++, then you can use [ATL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/exb5b09w(v=vs.94)) to consume SOAP-RPC encoded payloads, but you cannot easily consume SOAP-doc literal payloads.
2. For more information on consuming an ATL Server webservice from a sample client application, see the sample code (errata) for the [ATL Server book](https://www.google.com/search?q=ATLServer:HighPerformancec%20%20on.NET) on the apress website.